# Sequence not get current next number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sequence

I have a sequence like:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[DesignSequence] 
 AS [int]
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE 0
 MAXVALUE 2147483647
 CACHE 
GO
```

So in my table I have column with this sequence in `Default Value or Binding : (NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[DesignSequence])`

Problem is for some reason my next number is `4140`, but when I added new row to table it added number: `3627` . 
So now I have duplicate values. Why my sequence is failing? any reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequences aren't automatically synchronized with the existing data in your tables.  If you are adding a sequence to an existing table you need to set its `start with` appropriately.

You can [reset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) it like this:

```
declare @maxVal bigint = (select max(id) from DesignTable)
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = concat('alter sequence DesignSequence restart with ', @maxVal + 1)
print (@sql)
exec (@sql)
```